# Matching string with certain condition (regex)

Tags: php, regex

I need regex which will matching string like this:

if there is capital "T", then one number (any), then one dot and then 2 any symbol at the end of string.

Something like this:

```
$stingr = "alT4.ei";

if (match happens with $stingr ) {
    echo "match";
}
else {
    echo "no match";
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you got stuck with? What have you tried? Looks regex 101 to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this ?

```
$stingr = "alT4.ei";

if (preg_match("#T\d\..{2}$#", $stingr)) {
    echo "match";
}
else {
    echo "no match";
}
```